# Swapping .svg files for .png in javascripted html not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have some javascript I wrote ages ago that assembles tiny image files (32x32px) into glyphs in an imaginary language on a webpage (html). It was designed to work with PNG images. My method (below) simply builds an IMG tag from various calculated inputs, and the final arrangement of these IMGs on the page is achieved by another method that builds DIV tags and assigns positioning CSS classes. The method that grabs the PNG files is as follows (qq is an encapsulation object):

```
qq.img = function(str, alt) {
    return "<img src =\""+qq.PATH+str+".png\" alt=\""+alt+"\">";
}
```

I now want to swap these tiny (grainy) PNGs for SVGs. I have created the requisite SVG files in Inkscape, named them correctly and saved them in the right directory for **qq.img()** to find them, and modified **qq.img()** (see below) to append .svg rather than .png in the IMG tag. Nothing else in my code refers to the .png files, so I thought this would be all I needed to do.

```
qq.img = function(str, alt) {
    return "<img src =\""+qq.PATH+str+".svg\" alt=\""+alt+"\">";
}
```

But it doesn't work. Nothing displays. I can open the individual .svg files directly in a browser window, and they display fine. But the javascript doesn't pick them up.

I thought I might have to specify dimensions for the SVG files in my CSS, but doing that makes no difference - I'm still not getting anything.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a JSfiddle or codepen of your code.

Comment: What is your browser console saying - any errors? And I assume you don't really have a space after the src and before its = sign - could you look at the actual HTML you have in your inspector and see what that img element looks like?

Comment: Without seeing the content of the SVG, its a wild guess

Comment: Prateek - I'm afraid I don't know what a JSfiddle or a codepen is! :p

Comment: A Haworth - will check console and get back to you. Yes, there is a space there! Wasn't a problem with the .png files, but I'll remove it anyway and see if that helps. WIll check the html inspector as suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Danny - I'm not experienced using SVGs in html. Are you suggesting that the structure of the svg itself might be problematic? It was saved from Inkscape using default parameters. How can I determine if the content of the svg is an issue? Thanks.